# Holomorphic function injective on annulus $\Rightarrow$ injective on unit disk?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be analytic on the unit disc, and suppose that there is an annulus
$U = \{z ∈ C \mid r < |z| < 1\}$ such that $f(z)$ restricted to the annulus $U$ is
injective. Show that $f$ is injective on the unit disc.

I tried to show that $g(z) = f(z) - f(z_0)$ has only one zero in the unit disk, but how can I use the hypothesis of the annulus?

Comment: How about applying the Jordan Curve Theorem?

Comment: it works, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let $w \notin f(r\partial\mathbb{D})$, the number of zeros of the function $f(z)-w$ in $r\mathbb{D}$ are equal to $$|\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{r\partial\mathbb{D}}\frac{f'(j)}{f(j)-w}dj|=|\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{f(r\partial\mathbb{D})}\frac{1}{z-w}dz|=|ind_{f(r\partial\mathbb{D})}(w)|. $$So $f(z)-w$ has $0$ or $1$ zeros in $r\mathbb{D}$ ,since  $f(r\partial\mathbb{D})$ is a Jordan curve.\\ Since $w,r$ was arbitrary the proof follows.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not an answer, but it might be helpful. If not, I will trash it later.**

Note that $$\phi:z\mapsto \frac{1}{|z|}\Big(1-(1-r)|z|\Big) \cdot z,\quad 0\mapsto 0$$
maps any point of the open unit disk $D$ into the anulus $A$ - geometrically, it's just a circular inversion mapping $|z|\in(0,1)$ to $|\phi(z)|\in(r,1)$. More importantly, it's a bijection.

Fix $z_0\not=0$ and let

> $g(z)=f(\phi(z))-f(\phi(z_0))$

Then
$$g(z)=0\iff f(\phi(z))=f(\phi(z_0))$$
but $\phi(D-\{0\})=A$, so if $z\not=0$ then $\phi(z)=\phi(z_0)$ and so $z=z_0$.

We just need to see what happens if $z=0$. $f$ is analytic so
$$f(z)=f(0)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n z^n$$
Now $f(0)=f(\phi(z_0))$ if and only if
$$f(0)=f(0)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \phi(z_0)^n$$
that is $\phi(z_0)=0$, and so $z_0=0$.

> Therefore, $g(z)=0$ if and only if $z=z_0$ on the whole open unit disk.

Can you use this info somehow?

Comment: sorry, I still cannot see how this relates to the behavior of f on the whole disk. By change the domain of f to the domain of g, we did not know anymore about the behavior of f. The inversion map is interesting though.